# org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException using Spring Security and Session Registry

Tags: spring, spring-security

I need to know which users are online on the website and for this reason I'm using the session registry provided by Spring Security (`org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl`). Here is my Spring Security configuration:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">
    <beans:bean id="authenticationManager" class="my.package.security.AuthenticationManager" />

    <http disable-url-rewriting="true" authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager">
        <intercept-url pattern="/login*" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/*" access="ROLE_USER" />
        <form-login login-processing-url="/authorize" login-page="/login" authentication-failure-url="/login-failed" />
        <logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/login" />
        <session-management session-authentication-strategy-ref="sas" invalid-session-url="/invalid-session" />
    </http>

    <beans:bean id="sessionRegistry" class="org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl"/>

    <beans:bean id="sas" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy">
        <beans:constructor-arg name="sessionRegistry" ref="sessionRegistry" />
        <beans:property name="maximumSessions" value="1" />
    </beans:bean>
</beans:beans>
```

As you can see, I'm using a custom authentication manager (my.package.security.AuthenticationManager):

```
public class AuthenticationManager implements org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager
{
    @Autowired
    UserJpaDao userDao;

    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException
    {
        User loggedInUser = null;
        Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = null;

        ...

        loggedInUser = loggedInUser = userDao.findByAlias(authentication.getName());
        if(loggedInUser != null)
        {
            // Check password etc.
            grantedAuthorities = loggedInUser.getAuthorities();
        }
        else
        {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Unknown username");
        }

        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(loggedInUser, authentication.getCredentials(), grantedAuthorities);
    }
}
```

Because of this, `sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals()` will return a list of `User`s (`List<Object>` "castable" to `List<User>`). I would like to mantain this because it's exactly what I need.

Now, the problem is that `User` is my own class and contains ManyToMany and OneToMany relationships. For this reason, I get a `org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException` when calling `sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals()`. I guess that it happens because this method is not called inside a Transaction, but how can I prevent this exception to happen?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not store the user object, but the user id.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @Ralph. This is something I thought about. But it's more convenient in my way, right? Otherwise I always have to query the database every time I need to get the online users list. What is the disadvantage doing it in my way?

Comment: @satoshi: What is the disadvantage doing it in my way? A LazyInitializationException -- You need to merge the object in anyway into your current hibernate session. If you do not load them from db, you will need to think of concurrent modification and a lot of other problems.

Comment: @satoshi: To be honest, one way to handle problems is just to avoid them -- my answer is nothing more. It will not solve the problem, but may it is a solution not to have to deal with that problem.